# How does Ocaml decide precedence for user-defined operators?

Tags: ocaml

I want nice operators for complex arithmetic to make my code more readable. Ocaml has a Complex module, so I just want to add operators that call those functions.

The most intuitive way for me is to make a new complex operator from all of the usual operators by appending '&' to the operator symbol. Thus +& and *& will be complex addition and multiplication. I would also like ~& to be complex conjugation.

If I'm going to use these operators, I want them to associate the same way that normal arithmetic associates. Based on the following sessions, they are automatically behaving the way I want, but I would like to understand why, so that I don't get horrible bugs when I introduce more operators.

My current guess is that their precedence is done by lexically sorting the operator symbols according to an ordering that is consistent with normal arithmetic precedence. But I cannot confirm this.

Session one:

```
# open Complex;;
# let (+&) a b = add a b;;
val ( +& ) : Complex.t -> Complex.t -> Complex.t = <fun>
# let ( *&) a b = mul a b;;
val ( *& ) : Complex.t -> Complex.t -> Complex.t = <fun>
# one +& zero *& one +& zero *& one;;
- : Complex.t = {re = 1.; im = 0.}
# zero +& one *& zero +& one *& zero;;
- : Complex.t = {re = 0.; im = 0.}
# i +& i *& i +& i *& i *& i;;
- : Complex.t = {re = -1.; im = 0.}
```

Session two:

```
# open Complex;;
# let ( *&) a b = mul a b;;
val ( *& ) : Complex.t -> Complex.t -> Complex.t = <fun>
# let (+&) a b = add a b;;
val ( +& ) : Complex.t -> Complex.t -> Complex.t = <fun>
# one +& zero *& one +& zero *& one;;
- : Complex.t = {re = 1.; im = 0.}
# zero +& one *& zero +& one *& zero;;
- : Complex.t = {re = 0.; im = 0.}
# i +& i *& i +& i *& i *& i;;
- : Complex.t = {re = -1.; im = 0.}
# let (~&) a = conj a;;
val ( ~& ) : Complex.t -> Complex.t = <fun>
# (one +& i) *& ~& (one +& i);;
- : Complex.t = {re = 2.; im = 0.}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> In general, the associativity and precedence of an operator (unless you go out to camlp4 or something) is based on the operator's first character.

[source](http://alan.petitepomme.net/cwn/2004.07.27.html) (look for for "Associativity precedence for the user-defined operator").

There is no way to define it explicitly in OCaml (see [this](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/ml-archives/caml-list/2002/05/8972a64c134fa2f30b05b8a79df793ef.en.html) and also "User-defined infix operators" on [Comparing Objective Caml and Standard ML](http://adam.chlipala.net/mlcomp/))

You can use [camlp4](http://pauillac.inria.fr/camlp4/) or [camlp5](http://cristal.inria.fr/~ddr/camlp5/) to explicitly define the order of infix function. It seems like [pa_do](http://pa-do.forge.ocamlcore.org/) can also be an option.

I tried to write an example but I am not familiar with camlp4 and it is not easy to learn in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sort of annoyed that the correct answer is not more useful and/or awesome. I too am not familiar enough with p4/p5 to use it.

Comment: Great link(s). I was going to mention camlp{4,5}, but fixing the precedence of operators was only a mean in the original question. The end was to make the code future-proof. I doubt any solution involving camlp{4,5} is a good solution towards this goal; it is certainly a dependency I try to avoid, although it is often tempting.

Answer (score 14):

It's right in the OCaml manual, [section 6.7](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html), scroll down, right before section 6.7.1. The precedence table has some things like `+...`, which includes any user-defined starting with `+`. It is not true that it always depends on the first character, as `**...` has higher precedence than `*...`.

Answer (score 3):

The pa-do syntax extension for OCaml addresses exactly this issue:

http://pa-do.forge.ocamlcore.org/

You can use it to change operator precedence, or, more usefully in this case, use explicit context to change the meaning of operators.